# Como reiniciar un objeto JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo una variable que guarda un objeto

```
var gData = {};
```

clase para crear el objeto

```
class Automate{
  constructor(){
    this.nodes = [];
    this.links = [];
    }
}
```

instancio y creo un nuevo objeto

```
var automateObject = new Automate();
```

y finalmente asigno el objeto a la variable

```
gData = automateObject;
```

Como puedo hacer posible que en algun punto eliminar toda la informacion que contiene el objeto gData e insertarle nuevos datos

He intentado utilizar la funcion "Delete" de javascript, por ejemplo

```
delete gData.nodes
delete gData.links
```

Pero al final no elimina las propiedad, sino que sigue agregando al momento de agregarle nuevo datos

```
   function parseContent(content) {
delete gData.nodes;
delete gData.links;
        var lines = content.split("\n");
        //Creation de l'automate
        var automateObject;
        //Parcourir tout le fichier
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
          //Pour creer l'onbjet automate
            if(lines[i].length > 1){
              if(i == 0){
                var currentline = lines[i].split("\n");
                currentline = lines[i].replace(/[\(\)]/g, '');  
                currentline = currentline.replace(/,/g, '');   
                currentline = currentline.split(" ");
                automateObject = new Automate();
                const eta1 = new Etat(parseInt(currentline[1]),'RED');
                ets.push(eta1);
              } else {
                //variable pour stocker le titre et la couleur
                var label;
                //variable pour couper chaque ligne du fichier
                var currentline = lines[i].split("\n");
                  //Enlever les parenthese de la chaine de characters
                  currentline = lines[i].replace(/[\(\)]/g, '');
                  //Enlever les citations de la chaine
                  currentline = currentline.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
                  //Couper la chaine en 3 morceaux
                  currentline = currentline.split(",",3);
                  //Couper le deuxieme atribut pour obtenir le nom de lien et la couleur
                  label = currentline[1].split(":");
                  //Creation d'un object de type automate
                  const tran = new Transition(parseInt(currentline[0]),label[0],label[1],parseInt(currentline[2]));
                  //Ajouter l'object dans l'array
                  trans.push(tran);
                  validateEtat(parseInt(currentline[0]));
                  validateEtat(parseInt(currentline[2]));
              }
            }
        }
    automateObject.nodes = ets; 
    automateObject.links = trans;
    gData = automateObject;
    console.log(gData);
    }
```

Comment: Has intentado simplemente reasignar la clase? En lugar de usar el delete colocar "= new Automate();"

Comment: la forma mas simple sería crear una nueva instancia y que el garbage collector se encargue de la instancia anterior, otra forma que se me ocurre es agregarle un metodo setdefaults que lo llamas en el constructor y asi reutilizas la instancia

Answer (score 6):

Te resumo tu código para que veas el problema:

```
function parseContent(content) {
    delete gData.nodes; //Borras el atributo
    delete gData.links; //Borras el atributo
    ...
    var automateObject; //declaras variable
    //Parcourir tout le fichier
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        ...
               //asignas un objeto a la variable
                automateObject = new Automate(); 

        ...
            }
        }
    }
    //rellenas los datos en la variable
    automateObject.nodes = ets;
    automateObject.links = trans;
    //gData borra su antiguo objeto y se le asigna uno nuevo
    gData = automateObject;
    console.log(gData); //muestras el valor de automateObject, que es lo guardado
}
```

La penúltima línea hace que las dos primeras de la función sean totalmente irrelevantes.

Comment: Aunque el error no tenía nada que ver con el delete en sí, añado este enlace donde explican muy bien cómo actua: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: Gracias estaré leyendo el post